# PowerShell Find and Replace in file issues

Tags: powershell

I am having trouble finding how to find and replace in a file using poweshell. The file has several lines that are similar. I need to change the "ACT" to "RDY" in the line that starts with <PC_4 . All Lines start with < and end with >.

The Code:

```
powershell -Command(Get-Content C:\testfodler\test.XML) -replace '<PC_4 SET_THING="ACT">', '<PC_4 SET_THING="RDY">' | Out-File -encoding ASCII myFile.txt
```

The error I get is:

```
The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
Not all parse errors were reported.  Correct the reported errors and try again.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RedirectionNotSupported
```

Running this on a windows 10 machine.

Comment: Read `PowerShell.exe -?` and follow the `-Command` section: To write a string that runs a Windows PowerShell command, use the format: `"& {<command>}"` where the quotation marks indicate a string and the invoke operator (`&`)  causes the command to be executed…

Comment: @JosefZ - Sorry i'm out of my depth on this. Is the following what your saying to do?

`powershell -Command "&{(Get-Content C:\testfodler\test.XML)}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should quote the value (code) passed to the `-Command` parameter because it expects a string. How you quote depends on how you call `powershell.exe`.

If you are in PowerShell or CMD and are calling powershell.exe, you may surround the code passed to `-Command` with double quotes and double quote escape (`""`) inner double quotes, which is the PowerShell layer of escaping. Then backslash escape the escaping quote, which is for the cmd layer of escaping.

```
powershell.exe -command "(Get-Content C:\testfolder\test.XML) -replace '<PC_4 SET_THING=\""ACT\"">', '<PC_4 SET_THING=\""RDY\"">' | Set-Content myfile.txt -encoding ASCII"
```